# Accessing Windows Network Share from Web Service Securely

Tags: web-services, security, network-share

We have developed a RESTful Web Service which requires access to a Network share in order to read and write files.  This is a public facing Web Service (running over SSL) which requires staff to log on using an assigned user name and password.

This web service will be running in a DMZ.  It doesn't seem "right" to access a Network Share from a DMZ.  I would venture a guess that the "secure" way to do this would be to provide another service *inside the domain* which *only* talks to our Web Service.  That way, if anyone wanted to exploit it, they would have to find a way to do it via the Web Service, not through known system API's.

Is my solution "correct"?  Is there a better way?

Notes:

- the Web Service does *not* run under IIS.
- the Web Service currently runs under an account with access to the Network Share and access to a SQL database.
- the Web Service is intended only for designated staff, not the public.
- I'm a developer, not an IT professional.

Answer (score 0):

What about some kind of vpn to use the internal ressources? There are some pretty solutions for this, and opening network shares to the internet seems too big a risk to do.

That aside, when an attacker breaks into your DMZ host using those webservices, he can break into your internal server using the same API unless you can afford to create two complete different solutions.

When accessing the fileservers from the DMZ directly, you would limit theses connections using a firewall so even after breaking your DMZ Host the attacker cannot do "everything" but only read (write?) to those servers.

I would suggest #2